# How to get the column name of a dataframe from values in a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a df with 15 columns:
df.columns:

```
    0  class
    1  name
    2  location
    3  income
    4  edu_level
    --
    14 marital_status
```

after some transformations I got an `numpy.ndarray` with shape (15,3) named `loads`:

```
0.52   0.33   0.09
0.20   0.53   0.23
0.60   0.28   0.23
0.13   0.45   0.41
0.49   0.9
so on  so on  so on
```

So, 3 columns with 15 values.

**What I need to do:**

I want to get the `df column` name of the values  from the first column of `loads` that are greater then .50

For this example, the columns of df related to the first column of `loads`with values higher than 0.5 should return:

```
0 Class
2 Location
```

Same for the second column of `loads`, should return:

```
1 name
3 income
4 edu_level
```

and the same logic to the 3rd column of `loads`.

I managed to get the numparray `loads` they way I need it but I am having a bad time with this last part.  I know I can simple manually pick the columns but this will be a hard task when df has more than 15 features.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your threshold you can create a boolean array in order to filter df.columns:

```py
threshold = .5

for j in range(loads.shape[1]):
      print(df.columms[loads[:,j]>threshold])
```